# con el segundo click si se me activa el select

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, pero solo me funciona cuando le doy dos el segundo click para activar el checkbox

```
    function uncheck() {
    
        var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("sNombre_centro");
        var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("sNombre_formacion");

    checkbox1.onclick = function() {
        $("#nombre_centro option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("sNombre_centro").checked;
        document.getElementById("nombre_centro").disabled = !isChecked;
        if (checkbox1.checked == true) {
           $("#nombre_formacion option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
            checkbox2.checked = null;
        }
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("sNombre_formacion").checked;
        document.getElementById("nombre_formacion").disabled = !isChecked;
        
    }

    checkbox2.onclick = function() {
        $("#nombre_formacion option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("sNombre_formacion").checked;
        document.getElementById("nombre_formacion").disabled = !isChecked;
        if (checkbox2.checked == true) {
            $("#nombre_centro option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
            checkbox1.checked = null;
        }
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("sNombre_centro").checked;
        document.getElementById("nombre_centro").disabled = !isChecked;
        
    }
}

echo '<input type="checkbox" name="sNombre_centro" id="sNombre_centro"   onClick="uncheck()"/>';
echo "Centros: ";
echo '<select class="input"   name="nombre_centro" id="nombre_centro" disabled>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="sNombre_formacion" id="sNombre_formacion"   onClick="uncheck()"/>';
echo "Formaciones: ";
echo '<select  class="input"   name="nombre_formacion" id="nombre_formacion" disabled>';
```

el problema que tengo es que solo se activa cuando le doy el segundo click de activacion al checkbox, y lo quer quiero lograr es que se active el select asociado al checkbox al primer click

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué quieres lograr y qué problema o error tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completarla.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecútala al final y te funcionará desde el primer click.

```js
function uncheck() {

    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("sNombre_centro");
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("sNombre_formacion");

    checkbox1.onclick = function() {
        $("#nombre_centro option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("sNombre_centro").checked;
        document.getElementById("nombre_centro").disabled = !isChecked;
        if (checkbox1.checked == true) {
           $("#nombre_formacion option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
            checkbox2.checked = null;
        }
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("sNombre_formacion").checked;
        document.getElementById("nombre_formacion").disabled = !isChecked;
        
    }

    checkbox2.onclick = function() {
        $("#nombre_formacion option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("sNombre_formacion").checked;
        document.getElementById("nombre_formacion").disabled = !isChecked;
        if (checkbox2.checked == true) {
            $("#nombre_centro option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
            checkbox1.checked = null;
        }
        var isChecked = document.getElementById("sNombre_centro").checked;
        document.getElementById("nombre_centro").disabled = !isChecked;
        
    }
}

uncheck();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="sNombre_centro" id="sNombre_centro"   onClick="uncheck()"/>'
Centros: "
<select class="input"   name="nombre_centro" id="nombre_centro" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" name="sNombre_formacion" id="sNombre_formacion"   onClick="uncheck()"/>
Formaciones: 
<select  class="input"   name="nombre_formacion" id="nombre_formacion" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué uncheck() es una función?
Deberías cargar todo lo que tienes en uncheck() desde el principio, no en el onclick de cada checkbox.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]